# How does this JS function work

Tags: javascript

```
function getDaysInMonth(y, m) {
   return /8|3|5|10/.test(--m)?30:m==1?(!(y%4)&&y%100)||!(y%400)?29:28:31;
}
getDaysInMonth(2012, 1);
```

Hello guys! Please help me understand this code to more readable for me, i'm just started learn js.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation on how this function works, or are you looking for a less convoluted solution?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst write a function that is more readable, thank you

Comment: I want to edit the question, But it hurts my head. Does he want it encrypted? Or to understand what it does? What is procedure when a question is so.. questionable.

Comment: decrypt / encrypt .. to-may-to / to-mah-to

Comment: @Spaceman write a function that is more readable, thank you (sorry :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`condition ? result1 : result2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx) ternary operator is just the same as:

```
if (condition)
    result1
else
    result2
```

So, if you expand it, then you will get the following code:

```
function getDaysInMonth(y, m)
{
    m = m - 1; // For some reasons, the author decided to use 0-based month
    if (/8|3|5|10/.test(m)) // April, June, September, November
        return 30;

    if (m == 1) // February
    {
        if ((!(y % 4) && y % 100) || !(y % 400)) // Leap year check
            return 29;
        else
            return 28;
    }

    return 31; // Other monthes
}
```

The only confusing thing is

```
/8|3|5|10/.test(m)
```

That's the same as the following, but using RegExp:

```
if (m == 8 || m == 3 || m == 5 || m == 10)
```

Using RegExp when it is possible to not use it is considered a bad practice. It is definitely not a best function which calculates this, I've ever seen.

There is a proper way which is suggested by user Jaromanda X.
Another easy way is to have an array:

```
function getDaysInMonth(y, m)
{
    if (m == 2) // February
    {
        if ((!(y % 4) && y % 100) || !(y % 400)) // Leap year check
            return 29;
        else
            return 28;
    }

    var daysInMonthes = [31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    return daysInMonthes[m - 1];
}
```

Comment: @vc2designer Probably, the author was too lazy to write 4 OR conditions or he wanted to make this code shorter. Honestly said, it is considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: better way :) - return m===2?(y%4||!(y%100)&&(y%400))?28:29:30+(m+(m>>3)&1);

Answer (score 0):

I realise it doesn't answer the question, but in all seriousness I think one needs to use a hammer to drive in a nail, not a wheelbarrow and shovel

Here you go - this uses the Date object to perform a Date specific calculation for a Date

```
function getDaysInMonth(y, m) {
    return (new Date(y, m, 0)).getDate();
}
getDaysInMonth(2012, 1);
```

This produces the same result without the bullshit of RegExp and "ternary" ( `?` `:` ) gymnastics required in the example given

Another alternative (with a single `ternary` front somersault with half twist)

```
function getDaysInMonth(y, m) {
    return [31, ((!(y % 4) && y % 100 !== 0) || !(y % 400)) ? 29 : 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][m - 1];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is a more readable for I would advise a switch.

```
function getDaysInMonth(year, monthIn)
{
    monthIn = monthIn - 1; // For some reasons, the author decided to use 0-based month

    switch(monthIn){
        case 1: // February
            // Leap year check
            if ((!(year % 4) && year % 100) || !(year % 400))
                return 29;
            else
                return 28;
        case 3 : // April
        case 5 : // June
        case 8 : // September
        case 10: // November
            return 30;
        default: // All Other Months
            return 31;
    }
}
```